# Problems Inject Parameters on query_builder inside the buildForm Symfony 2.5

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I'm encountering some problem with Symfony 2.5. I need to dynamically modify a form based on some parameters that I pass from the controller but I can't initialize the $options array to the task.

My Files:

```
    // ordersContrroller.php
         $orders=new OrdersM();
    
            $form = $this->createForm(new ListOrdersType(), $orders, array('id'=>1));

    // ListOrdersType.php
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Event\DataEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;


class ListOrdersType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
        {   
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                    'data_class' => 'Acme\MyBundle\Form\Model\OrdersM',
                    'id'=>1,        
             ));
            
        }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        var_dump(array_keys($options));
        $builder->add('orders', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AcmeMyBundle:Orders',
                'property' => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function($repository) use ($options) {
                        return $repository->createQueryBuilder('o')
                        ->where('o.id='.$options['id'])
                        ->orderBy('o.id', 'ASC' )
                        ;
                    }
        ));
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'orders';
    }
}
```

I've TWO distinct problems. When i put the options array in che controller
array('id'=>1)

i recive the following error:

> The option "id" does not exist. Known options are: "action", "attr",
> "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "cascade_validation",
> "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message",
> "csrf_protection", "csrf_provider", "csrf_token_id",
> "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data",
> "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message",
> "inherit_data", "intention", "invalid_message",
> "invalid_message_parameters", "label", "label_attr", "mapped",
> "max_length", "method", "pattern", "post_max_size_message",
> "property_path", "read_only", "required", "translation_domain",
> "trim", "validation_groups", "virtual"

Like the option is not declared during the declaration of the defaults options of the resolver.

And of course when I try to use the $options array on the key $option['id'] on the query_builder function, I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: id in
> ****/Form/Type/ListOrdersType.php
> line 56

that ofc is this one:

```
->where('o.id='.$options['id'])
```

The id $option is ony one, but I really need to make my query in the EntityType.php files dynamic following different parameters. I really need to pass them over options in some way.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you concatenating your values instead of using binding? Try to utilize `setParameter()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this (`getDefaultOptions` changed to `setDefaultOptions`):

```
class ListOrdersType extends AbstractType
{
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
        {   
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                    'data_class' => 'Acme\MyBundle\Form\Model\OrdersM',
                    'id'=> null,        
             ));

        }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {    
        $builder->add('orders', 'entity', array(
                ...
                'query_builder' => function($repository) use ($options) {
                        return $repository->createQueryBuilder('o')
                        ->where('o.id= :id')
                        ->orderBy('o.id', 'ASC' )
                        ->setParameter('id', $options['id'])
                        ;
                    }
        ));
    }

    ...
}

$orders=new OrdersM();
$form = $this->createForm(new ListOrdersType(), $orders, array('id'=>1));
```

Comment: my bad cant see that eheh , tx alot you give me a great help. Now everthing works.